# setTimeout and clearTimeout assigning to var and specifies

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

```
var nothover = function(){window.setTimeout(function() {
     $('#proFBfeel').hide();
      $('#proFBfeel .moreinfos').html('');
       $('.contact_pro').html('');
     },3000);
   };
  $('#proFBfeel').nothover();
    $('#proFBfeel').hover(function() {
        window.clearTimeOut(nothover);
     });
         $('html').click(function() {
           $('#proFBfeel').hide();
            $('#proFBfeel .moreinfos').html('');
             $('.contact_pro').html('');
          });
```

Ok so as you can see in what I assigned the var `nothover` is the setTimeout

After three seconds I want the function to run, UNLESS the object is hovered. And if it is hovered to clear the time out.

Then Once back outside of the object to run the function again or unless they click the HTML element which then hides the object.

This is not running properly though it says for me

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nothover'

Why is this? And if someone can help I'd be greatly appreciate this. By Help I mean explain a little of the javascript functions and how I'd go about making sure these run properly.

Thank You

Comment: You're trying to invoke a global function `nothover` as a jQuery plugin...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` returns a value.  If you want to "cancel" the timeout, you supply the value to `clearTimeout`.  You **don't** pass your function to `clearTimeout`.  That will not do anything.  No one in this thread seems to have noticed that.  Here is documentation on this: [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

Here is working code:

```
var notHover = function() {
   var timerId = setTimeout(function () {
      $('#proFBfeel').hide();
      $('#proFBfeel .moreinfos').html('');
      $('.contact_pro').html('');  
    }, 3000);

    // return a function which will cancel the timer
    return function () { clearTimeout(timerId); };
};

// start the timer.  We can call cancelTimer() if we want to cancel it
var cancelTimer = notHover();

$('#proFBfeel').hover(function() {
    // mouse in, cancel the notHoverTimer
    if (cancelTimer) {
        cancelTimer();
        cancelTimer= undefined;
    }
}, function () {
    // mouse out, start the timer again
    cancelTimer = notHover();
});
```

```

Comment: Brandon, this did wonderful. And thank you for the comments in the code as well

Answer (score 1):

To add a method to the jQuery object you have to do `$.fn.nothover = function(){` ... What you have there is just an assignment of a function expression to a variable, which in no way will affect jQuery.

Comment: oh ok well let me try, and if it works upvote for you :) So when ever I want to assign the setTimeout function in a "var" i should use $.fn.nothover?

Comment: Wait... are you trying to use the `nothover` method to also set up the behavior that occurs if the user *doesn't* hover over the element?

Comment: Ok so this worked like a beast! Thank you very much! Though after clicking the HTML to hide as well it clears the time out I think or something. I need to make sure the timeout is constantly ran. Maybe I should run setInterval, then clearInterval?

Comment: Yeah basically. I need to make the element appear on hover of one element. Then it will hide if the user doesn't hover the shown object. Or they can click HTML to hide it as well. It needs to always be alive though so that it runs each time the user hovers the first element.

Another note is, when I hover the shown object too it says same error?

Comment: Wait... I'm a little confused by what you mean: "It needs to always be alive though so that it runs each time the user hovers the first element." I thought you're using the hover to cancel out any sort of behavior...

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.nothover = function () {
    function hideIt() {
        this.hide();
        this.find(".moreinfos").html("");
    }
    this.hover(function () {
        window.clearTimeout(hideIt);
    });
    window.setTimeout(hideIt, 3000);
};
```

Is this along the lines of what you're trying to do...?

In this code I'm defining a jQuery plugin by defining a property on the `$.fn` object. Within this plugin I define a function `hideIt` which contains the code that you seem to want to invoke after the 3 seconds *unless* the user hovers over the element in question in which case we clear the 3 second timeout. Is that right?

**Attempt #2**

Maybe something like this...?

```
$.fn.nothover = function () {
    function initialize() {
        window.setTimeout(doSomething, 3000);
    }

    function doSomething() {
        // do something
    }

    this.hover(function () {
        window.clearTimeout(doSomething);
    }, initialize);

    initialize();
};
```

Closer?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/itugop/1/edit that is what I want, except to run each time. I'm not positive on the clearTimeout if it destroys the setTimeout completely or only while it is in hover

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off setting a flag to true or false when you mouseover or mouseout, and then having the function in the timeout just check for the truthiness of that flag before executing the behavior.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to clearTimeout. Well maybe I do technically. Won't the clearing, then when you rehover it sets the settimeout again correct since the settimeout is in the scope of the hover function. I'm just getting these errors, it almost worked perfectly, just need that one last bug fixed :)

Comment: Is something like my second attempt closer?

Comment: I can see what you did there, but why the second function of dosomething? I mean shouldn't initialize and dosomething have same?